# symbol versioning and dlsym

Tags: c, linker, shared-libraries

I load the pthread library in my program using `dlopen`, and fetch handlers to `pthread_create` and `pthread_join` using `dlsym`.

How can I ensure that both the handlers are of a compatible version? I do not care if the symbols are of new version or old versions. I just want that whatever `pthread_create` I use to work well with the `pthread_join` that I get.

I know there is a `dlvsym` to which I can pass explicit version number, but I do not care about exact version numbers as I want my code to be independent of library versions.

Comment: I do believe you can safely assume that pthread_create and pthread_join provided by the *same* library will be compatible.

Comment: The question is will dlsym return compatible symbols. I am not linking against the library at command line, rather use dlopen and dlsym to fetch the handlers.

Comment: Late to this, but reading the above, I wonder -- I don't see how using `dlopen` as opposed to leaving it to the traditional implicit dynamic linking, has anything to do with validity of Erik's comment -- if you use `dlopen` to obtain a handle to a library of your choosing, rest assured `_join` and `_create` are pretty much guaranteed to work with one another, given how they are part of the same dynamic library object built from source code where they were designed to work with one another?

Comment: It might be late, but you should know that libpthread is a special beast: if your program was originally compiled/linked without libpthread, it might very well fail if you try to use libpthread run-time (eg from a plugin or with dlopen/dlsym).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only reason the versioning exists is for a poor attempt at ABI-compatibility with programs compiled against *ancient* versions of glibc, which will not actually work anyway. (They've silently broken the ABI at least once in a way that, as far as I can tell, cannot be compatible.) Just ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need "dladdr - find the shared object containing a given address".

However as you have not said what platform you are using, so it might not be available.

Have a look and see..

Comment: Can any one help me how to pass the "version" in dlvsym