# dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "msgctl") does not return the default version

Tags: c, glibc, dlsym

If a library defines multiple version of the same symbol, `dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "symbol")` returns the older symbol even though the older symbol is not the default symbol.

For example, libpthread defines two versions of pthread_cond_broadcast:

```
$:> nm -g /lib64/libpthread-2.15.so|grep pthread_cond_broadcast
000000000000bfc0 T pthread_cond_broadcast@@GLIBC_2.3.2
000000000000c310 T pthread_cond_broadcast@GLIBC_2.2.5
```

- "GLIBC_2.3.2" is the default version that you get when linking with libpthread (without any dlsym involvement). (Notice the "@@" which signifies the default symbol)
- "GLIBC_2.2.5" is an older version

Now, if I use dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "pthread_cond_broadcast"), I always get the GLIBC_2.2.5 version and not the GLIBC_2.3.2 version. Of course one can use dlvsym to get the default version, but that gets complicated if one needs to do it for a large number of symbols and a lot of them have different new/old versions.

I do understand that RTLD_NEXT shouldn't always return the latest symbol to maintain compatibility, but why not return the default symbol?

Does anyone know about the rationale behind this?

Comment: I just came across the following question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12342133/pthread-cond-broadcast-broken-with-dlsym?rq=1
There is a pointer to:
http://blog.fesnel.com/blog/2009/08/25/preloading-with-multiple-symbol-versions/
which describes that dlsym always returns the older symbol, disregarding the default ("@@") version. So, I guess, nothing can be done unless someone has any suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been reported as a glibc bug:

- [dlsym(handle, "foo") and dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "foo") return different result with versioned "foo"](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=14932)

As far as I know, it has not been fixed yet.

Comment: `dlsym` does not call `malloc` if it succeeds. The current glibc implementation uses `malloc` to save the error message for `dlerror` in case of failure. An interposing `malloc` which uses `RTLD_NEXT` could have a fallback allocator to deal with such reantrancy issues.

Comment: You will have to check the implementation or ask on `libc-help` for advice. I do not expect the usual modes of `dladdr1` to call `malloc`, but there could be special modes which do.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of `RTLD_NEXT` is to return the symbol after the first, default one. Aren't you just looking for `RTLD_DEFAULT`?

Comment: I have preloaded a library which puts wrappers around certain symbols. In order to call the libc version, it then uses dlsym(RDLD_NEXT, ...)